# How to clone a HttpServletResponse object

Tags: servlets

I have a HttpServletresponse object which gets committed after a actionperform operation.

I have a weird requirement where i have to re-use the committed response(same object used earlier) to call a new actionperform.

I tried to send a cloned Response objectby keeping the original Response intact. But cloning is not supported for HttpServletResponse.

Is there any way of refreshing the HttpServletResponse object?
Is it possible to create a HttpServletResponse object ?

Comment: I have same requirement. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html)

Comment: That does not work. Actual response will be modified , since we are passing it to HttpServletResponseWrapper

Comment: It won't be modified. You can modify the response if required.

Comment: What are all the values i have to clear in a committed response object. I will create a wrapper for response and i will have isCommitted() method which i will return false. But if i call reset() it may still throw IllegalStateException . How to handle this.